# Is it possible to open a C socket to an internet address through bluetooth

Tags: c, linux, sockets, bluetooth, iot

I am asked to connect my device to a server via a bluetooth connexion, such as an android tablet that gives an internet access via bluetooth.

The software on my device is entirely C, and the device runs a debian.

I know how to use regular network sockets, and how to use bluetooth sockets, which is practically the same.

but I have strictly no idea how I could use some sort of bluetooth gateway to access the internet, IE what if I want to write on a socket that's open with a distant server over the internet... through a bluetooth socket? As far as I'm concerned, the bluetooth sockets I open are strictly reserved to the machine I am in direct connexion with.

An  application on the side of the android/ios device is apparently out of question.

Is this actually possible, and if yes, where should I look?

Comment: This is not your app's responsibility to manage, it is the OS's responsibility. If the device establishes a Bluetooth gateway session with the server, then your app should be able to create a standard TCP/IP or UDP socket and transmit data over it, letting the device's OS route the data over the Bluetooth connection and the server route the data over the Internet. Your app should not care HOW it is connected to the Internet, only that it is. That is the whole point of network routing and transport providers.

Comment: Bluetooth host stacks supports , Personal Area Networking(PAN) profile. The profile exactly does , what is mentioned in your question. If Bluetooth PAN profile is supported in your gateway device, you can complete the task with ease.